# Removing some whitespaces

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a string as below.

```
<freeForm>
   <text>FI77 1270 3000 0164 15</text>
</freeForm>
```

From the above xml portion i need to get the string like FI77 12703000 016415.

Please provide pointers to achieve the same using xslt1.0.

Answer (score -1):

It worked using translate() function in xslt.

Comment: Please note that `translate()` is an **XSLT 2.0** function; the OP asked for an **XSLT 1.0** solution.

Comment: @ABach, `translate()` *is* an XPath 1.0 function and *is* available in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev - you are absolutely correct; not sure what I was thinking. :) Kundan, my apologies.